# Loop MySql INSERT query. While or Foreach?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I'm struggling whit this...
Basically, I have a script that will run every day (cron job).
This script has to retrieve data from a table and it will post the data in another table (same database).

Here is my example script:

```
<?php

$c = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password");
$db = mysql_select_db("mydb", $c);


$query_sel = "SELECT id, rating, rating_count FROM mytableone";
$result_sel = mysql_query($query_sel) or die(mysql_error());
$ids = array();

while($id = mysql_fetch_array($result_sel))

    $ids[] = $row;

foreach($ids as $id){ 

$lid = $row['id'];
$etvalue = $row['user_rating'];
$etcount = $row['rating_count'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytabletwo VALUES ('$lid','$etvalue','$etcount',CURRENT_DATE())");

}
?>
```

My main idea is to insert data (as mysql query in foreach statement) "for each id from mytableone".

Where is my fault?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem exactly? How does it fail?

Comment: If you are concerned about multiple `INSERT INTO` queries, then just add transaction usage. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html Plus since you added `mysql` tag, you should probably read about it here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysql/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one SQL query

```
INSERT INTO mytabletwo SELECT id,rating,rating_count,CURRENT_DATE() FROM mytableone
```

As to the fault you are using $row instead of $id[...]

Comment: I have it, thank you. You're right. This is the simplest way. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is:

```
INSERT INTO mytabletwo(idColumnName, ratingColumnName, rating_countColumnName, dateColumnName) SELECT id, rating, rating_count, CURRENT_DATE() FROM mytableone;
```

(That is one statement.)