# What causes the additional raw in foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a for each loop which is used to print the serial numbers of a given sale item of an order, which was done based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18136883/1609555)

```
    if (($c["current_state"] == '16') || ($c["current_state"] == '4')) {
        $snlst = $mysqli->query("SELECT sn FROM ps_serials WHERE id_product={$aritmlst["product_id"]} AND id_order=$oid ORDER BY sn ASC");

        while ($id = mysqli_fetch_array($snlst)) {
            $ids[] = $id;
            foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
                echo "<tr><td class=\"label\" style=\"padding-left:15px\">Serial Number ".($key +1)."</td><td>".$id['sn']."</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
```

But the problem is that I get an additional table raw for my listing. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Try to move your foreach outside of your while loop, does that do the trick for you?

Comment: What if you use a different name for $id in the foreach loop?

Comment: I tried @Rizier123's suggestion. Now there are only two raws, but the 'Serial Number 1' and 'Serial Number 1' showing **1** and **2**

Comment: Err... May I ask how would you do that @RonaldPK :)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for two loops. IMHO this should be enough code:

```
if (($c["current_state"] == '16') || ($c["current_state"] == '4')) {
    $snlst = $mysqli->query("SELECT sn FROM ps_serials WHERE id_product={$aritmlst["product_id"]} AND id_order=$oid ORDER BY sn ASC");
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($snlst)) {
        $i++;
        echo '<tr><td class="label" style="padding-left:15px">Serial Number ' . $i . '</td><td>' . $row['sn'] . '</td></tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite this line:

```
while ($id = mysqli_fetch_array($snlst)) {
            $ids[] = $id;
            foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
                echo "<tr><td class=\"label\" style=\"padding-left:15px\">Serial Number ".($key +1)."</td><td>".$id['sn']."</td></tr>";
            }
        }
```

to this:

```
while ($id = mysqli_fetch_array($snlst)) {
    $ids[] = $id;       
}
foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
 echo "<tr><td class=\"label\" style=\"padding-left:15px\">Serial Number ".($key +1)."</td><td>".$id['sn']."</td></tr>";
            }
```

Comment: it works when there are multiple serials for one item. but when there are more than two items, **[this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vJeV5.jpg)** is the the output I get.

Answer (score 0):

then try a simple for loop, instead of a foreach loop:

```
for($i= 0; $i < count($ids); $i++)
{
  echo "<tr><td class=\"label\" style=\"padding-left:15px\">Serial Number ".($i+1)."</td><td>".$ids[$i]['sn']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Then I'm back to square 1